# ajax hardcoded value for ajax (newbie)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Can someone tell me how can I make a hardcoded value for the parameter of OnSuccess. This code was not mine. I think it was ajax but I am still confuse what it is.

Just focus onSuccess parameter "data"

```
function onSuccess(data) {
    if (data.result) {
        $.App_setLogin(data.data.key1, data.data.key2);
        window.location.href = data.data.url;
    }
}
```

I want to make a valid hardcoded parameter for onSuccess;
something like

```
data.data.key1 = "fname";
data.data.key2 = "lname";
data.data.url = "url";
```

Comment: yes then set parameter as you set in above code that works. set it above $.App_setLogin

Comment: Do you mean you want to return this data from a PHP script? Or just test this function with some known values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own example will work fine if added inside the `onSuccess` function. To have a seemingly valid parameter for an `onSuccess` call, you need the following fairly straightforward object

```
var param = {
    result: true,
    data: {
        key1: 'key 1',
        key2: 'key 2',
        url: 'url'
    }
};
//onSuccess(param);
```

Of course, all of this may not exactly help you reach your unstated goals.